# relationship between display and skew button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to skew a button. But the text was also affected by skewing.
Therefore, I gave the opposite angle(-21deg to 21deg) to the span that contains the text.

I gave **-21deg** to `.signin-btn` and **21deg** to `span` to reformat the text inside span to the right place that `.signin-btn` as affected.

However, it didn't work right away. But, it is working well when I added `display: inline-block;`
Can you tell me why it is working when `display: inline-block;` is inserted?

Thank you

```css
.signin-btn {
        width: 120px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 2px solid red;
        background-color: transparent;
        transform: skew(-21deg);
        border: 1.5px solid rgb(253, 101, 0);
        color: rgb(1, 2, 37);
        font-style: normal;
    }
    span {
        display: inline-block;
        transform: skew(21deg);
    }
```

```html
<button class="signin-btn"><span>Sign in</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default "Span" tag display value is inline.

with display: inline; doen't calculate any other value so when you are doing  transform: skew(21deg); so it is not working without display: inline-block; or block level

Please read below url you have got proper idea about that
[ref](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#aa-display-inline)